# Magento 2 Remove parent categories from subcategory URLs

Tags: magento2, category, url

I want to change category url to short url in magento 2 how it is possible?.
like :

> http://127.0.0.1/magentos/magento2/gear/bags.html

to

> http://127.0.0.1/magentos/magento2/bags.html

Answer (score 1):

Ans:- Please follow the below steps to avoid this problem.

Step1 :- Go to Admin -> Marketing -> SEO & Search -> URL Rewrites

Step2 :- Find the path by searching 'Request Path' column.

Step3 :- Clean the indexing php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Step4 :- Remove the cache php bin/magento cache:flush.

Step5 :- Refresh the front-end, click the main menu category then you can see the configured path.